# relatively positioned element doesn't take height of its children

Tags: html, css

I'm building a a little progress bar with css with the following html and scss(it's just scss because I'm using nesting)

html:

```
<div class="first">
  <div class="first__progress-bar-container"/>
  <div class="first__progress-bar"/>
  <div class="first__content-section">
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
  </div>  
</div>
<div class="second">more content</div>
```

scss:

```
.first {
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
  width: 1000px;

  &__progress-bar-container {
    position: absolute;
    background: #eee;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1
  }

  &__progress-bar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Can also use [this codepen](https://codepen.io/rv-akim/pen/dBEgJK)

If I see the result in the browser, the text `"more content"` sits right over all the `.content-section` content. I anticipated that `.second` would show up after `.content-section` and not on top of it.

Why doesn't the child element `.content-section` get evaluated into the height of parent element `.first`?

The follow up question is, how can I make it so `"more content"` appears after the first bit of content and not on top of it?

Comment: The absolute positioning is taking the elements out of the document flow. That's why .second is placed on top of the .first

Comment: but `.first__content-section` doesn't have absolute positioning. Does that mean that if any of an element's children is absolutely positioned, then it doesn't evaluate for height?

Comment: Could you please add valid markup?  As far as I know, <div /> isn't valid. Or are you working with XHTML?

Comment: I'm sorry i thought `div`'s could self close, i'll fix it.

Comment: oh whoa.... that changed it, ok, so self closing div's was my issue

Comment: I think i know my issue, its because `.first` has a fixed heigh of 10px

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm not sure if self closing divs are valid html, but they did produce different results in code pen.

If I just remove the fixed height from first it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the markup a little bit, assuming you want to put the progress-bar inside the progress-bar-container. If the progress-bar is inside the progress-bar-container, then you no longer need relative and absolute positioning. Removed the height from .first so that the size of .first is the size of the content.

SCSS:

```css
.first {

  width: 1000px;
  background-color:grey;

  &__progress-bar-container {
    background: #eee;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  &__progress-bar {

    height: 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="first">
  <div class="first__progress-bar-container">
    <div class="first__progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-section">
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
  </div>  
</div>
<div class="second"> more content</div>
```